# Debug infos with malloc in nano libc?

Tags: debugging, arm, malloc, gnu, newlib

I'm working with gnu arm tool chain and in my program I'm calling malloc several times. The calls to malloc work fine until some point it fails.
When I checked the free heap size and free stack, it shows that there is enough space to allocate.
The problem is I can't debug malloc from nano lib to see where it stuck because nano-lib is built without debug informations. 
Is there someone who can give me or redirect me to useful informations on how to rebuild the GNU ARM Libraries with debug informations ?

Thanks.

Comment: The heap maybe fragmented.  So you can have a 'free size' that is big enough, but there is no chunk that is big enough.  Are you sure that 'free heap size' is not a bunch of small chunks?  Try to allocate a bunch of smaller sizes.

Comment: I think it is heap fragmentation problem as I know that there is enough free space in the heap to malloc smaller chunk. But how to force the heap management to join all small free chunks in order to get big chunk in nano-lib ?

Comment: dlmalloc is already quite good at managing small allocation.  You need to look at your application and try to use 'slab' or 'objstack' allocation there.  Ie, allocate a big chunk and use your own allocator to manage the space; hopefully objects are of equal size.  Also, you can 'relocate' your objects then you may compact the space.  If they are all equal, there is no need as each will fit in any free slot.

Comment: The code is calling many times small allocations and is not freeing all of these small chunks instantly as It is needed. So, this is causing fragmentation problem, specially when I want to allocate big chunk. You talked about slab or objstack and allocator to manage the space. Some hints ? or links ?.

Comment: I use [google](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22slab+objects%22+OR+objstack) and have [GNU Objstack site](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Obstacks.html) and [slab allocation at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_allocation).  For Wikipedia on Slab, *It eliminates fragmentation caused by allocations and deallocations.* sounds like something you may benefit from.  You need a [pool allocator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool); slab is this plus it pre-initializes memory.